# ons-popover 内で ons-scrollerが使えない

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

ons-popover内にons-listを使用していくつかの機能を提供する、ドロップダウンメニューを作っています。　メニューの項目数が多いので、ons-scrollerでスクロールさせたいのですが、スクロールが機能せず、一部分のみしか表示されません。低い解像度の端末でも表示できるよう、スクロール機能を付けたいのですが、どのようにすればよいのでしょうか？

```js
ons.bootstrap();
ons.ready(function(){
  onReady();
});

function onReady(){
  ons.createPopover("PopOver.html");
}

function PopOverShowBtn(Target){
  var options={
    animation : "none"
  };
  PopOver.show(Target,options);

}
```

```html
<ons-navigator var="app_navi">

  <ons-page id="TopPage">
    <ons-button onclick="PopOverShowBtn(this);">ポップオーバー表示</ons-button>
  </ons-page>
</ons-navigator>

<ons-template id="PopOver.html">
  <ons-popover var="PopOver" cancelable style='width:300px'>
    <ons-scroller style="width:100%;height:400px;">
      <ons-list style="text-align:center">
        <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目１</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目２</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目３</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目４</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目５</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目６</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目７</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目８</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目９</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目１０</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目１１</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目１２</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目１３</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目１４</ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目１５</ons-list-item>

      </ons-list>
    </ons-scroller>
  </ons-popover>
</ons-template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自己解決できましたので、要点をまとめておきます。

問題点（調査中に発見した問題点を含む）
・Ons-Popover内のOns-Scrollerが機能しない。
・コンソール画面に「Onsen UI require jqLite. Load jQuery after loading AngularJS to fix this error. jQuery may break Onsen UI behavior.」と警告があった。(jQueryとOnsenUI(AngularJs)の併用、ロードの順番に関する警告)

対処法
・loader.jsファイルの削除
・必要なJSコンポーネントの再インストール

これにより、loader.jsが再作成され、警告の解消、Scrollerも機能するようになりました。

※loadr.jsの働きを良く理解していないため、削除によって及ぶ影響があるのかもしれません。乱暴な方法かもしれませんが、今のところ問題なく（ビルドも試しました）動作しています。

Answer (score 0):

質問に記載してあるコードで手元（プレビューとiOS版のデバッガ）ではスクロールが確認できましたが、それ以外の環境でのみ発生する事象でしょうか？

もしかしたらファイル構成やコードの記載場所等が問題の改善に繋がるかもしれないので、こちらで動作確認したコードを下記に記載します。

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/popover.js"></script>
    <script>
    ons.bootstrap();
    ons.ready(function(){
      onReady();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <ons-navigator var="app_navi">
    <ons-page id="TopPage">
      <ons-button onclick="PopOverShowBtn(this);">ポップオーバー表示</ons-button>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-navigator>
</body>
</html>
```

popover.js

```
function onReady(){
  ons.createPopover("PopOver.html");
}

function PopOverShowBtn(Target){
  var options={
    animation : "none"
  };
  PopOver.show(Target,options);
}
```

Popover.html

```
<ons-popover var="PopOver" cancelable style='width:300px'>
  <ons-scroller style="width:100%; height:300px;">
    <ons-list style="text-align:center">
      <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目１</ons-list-item>
      <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目２</ons-list-item>
      <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目３</ons-list-item>
      <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目４</ons-list-item>
      <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目５</ons-list-item>
      <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目６</ons-list-item>
      <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目７</ons-list-item>
      <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目８</ons-list-item>
      <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目９</ons-list-item>
      <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目１０</ons-list-item>
      <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目１１</ons-list-item>
      <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目１２</ons-list-item>
      <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目１３</ons-list-item>
      <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目１４</ons-list-item>
      <ons-list-item modifier='tappable'>項目１５</ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
  </ons-scroller>
</ons-popover>
```

Comment: コンソールを見ますと、
「Onsen UI require jqLite. Load jQuery after loading AngularJS to fix this error. jQuery may break Onsen UI behavior.」という警告があり、ロードする順序について警告されているものと思います。これらは、「Monaca」側でやってくれていることだと思うのですが、これが起因していることもあるのかもしれません。

Comment: @eclipse 手元で事象が再現できていないため具体的な解決策が出せず申し訳ないのですが、該当の警告（「Onsen UI require jqLite〜」）はOnsen UI（AngularJS）とjQueryを併用しているために出力されています（読み込む順番をOnsen UI, jQueryにすると警告自体は消えると思います）。メッセージにも「jQuery may break Onsen UI behavior.」とあるようにOnsen UIとjQueryの併用は難しい（やり方次第では可能のようです）ため、できるだけどちらかに絞って利用した方が良いと思います。

Comment: 細かく読んでくださってありがとうございます。
読み込む順番をOnsen UI, jQueryの順にするというのは、どこで設定できるのでしょうか？

Comment: @eclipse `<script src=〜></script>`の順番を変えるだけで大丈夫です。

Comment: 申し訳ありません。言葉が足りなかったかもしれません。
Monacaを使用している環境で、Monaca側で処理してくれているので、htmlに上記のような記述がありません。
おそらく、”loader.js”内部の処理なのではないかと思うのですが・・・・。

Comment: いただいたヒントを元に、Monaca側のloader.jsファイルを削除し、もう一度、JSコンポーネントを再設定し、その時に、OnsenUIをインストールしたのちにJqueryをインストールすることで、警告も消え、scrollerも動作するようになりました。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: @eclipse ご自身で試行錯誤した結果の解決なのであまりお役に立てた気はしませんが、無事に解決されたとのことで何よりです（ご面倒でなければ、自己回答を追加してそちらをベストアンサーにした方が良いかと思います）。お疲れさまでした。

Comment: いただいたヒントがなければたどり着くことができませんでした。感謝しています。
後程、回答を整理してまとめておきます。